# Non-plugin IRC bot

Tags: irc, bots

I'm looking for a highly configurable IRC bot. Only requisite: it must not be a plugin to an existing IRC client like mIRC.

Which is where I'm having trouble. IRC bots a plenty, but almost all of them are scripts for mIRC or Xchat. And I don't use any of those. And no, I'm not going to switch.

What I'm looking for is a program that I can start separately, it connects to the channels on the server of my choosing and sits there, doing what I instruct it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Eggdrops](http://www.eggheads.org/) are the way to go.

You start with the pure basic which you can configure, add plugins and customize in detail.

Comment: Looking at the instructions, this is meant for Linux/BSD. It says for Windows to, but there are no instructions for it.

Comment: For Windows, there are Windrops... See http://windrop.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 1):

I've got a PHP IRC Bot in development - find it on Facebook "Savant PHP IRC Bot".

Not a plugin, but does require PHP and PHP-CLI.